# Force of photons from the Sun hitting a football field = weight of 1 dime?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, momentum, thermal-radiation

I read, I think, some time ago that the "weight" of photons from the Sun hitting an area the size of a football field at noon on a sunny day would be about the "weight" of a dime?

Would appreciate it someone could flesh that out, verify if correct or false?

Answer (score 82):

Photons are massless so their weight is 0. However, photons do have momentum so they can exert force. This force is due to their momentum and would occur even in the absence of gravity, so it is not a weight.

The solar irradiance during peak hours is approximately $1000 \mathrm{ \ W \ m^{-2}}$ and the size of a football field is about $7200 \mathrm{ \ m^2}$ for a total radiant power of $7.2 \mathrm{ \ MW}$. Since $p=E/c$ and $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ we get that the force from this energy is $(7.2 \mathrm{\ MW})/c = 0.024 \mathrm{\ N}$.

In comparison, a dime has a mass of $2.268 \mathrm{\ g}$ which on the earth turns into a gravitational force, or weight, of $0.022 \mathrm{\ N}$.

So the force of the sunlight on a football field during peak solar hours is close to the weight of a dime.

Comment: I believe you're assuming 100% absorptance?  As the other answer's comment points out, if photons are reflected, you get twice the momentum transfer.

Comment: @JonCuster You must also consider the pressure of the outgoing infrared that results from the sunlight heating the field. So, the actual pressure will be intermediate between the perfect absorber and specular reflector cases.

Comment: I’ve purged a debate about introductory relativity. Please do that somewhere else.

Comment: Some additional comments removed. If anyone has concerns about “censorship,” please raise them on [meta], not here.

Comment: A clear and concise answer. I disagree that their momentum would occur in the absence of gravity since this is conjecture although a more precise statement, that the force they exert is independent of the magnitude of the Earth's gravity, I would agree with.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Would you like me to clarify or are you happy as-is?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen there's a minor defect in the answer insofar as it claims momentum would occur in the absence of gravity.  I pointed out the true fact that's an unscientific statement backed up by neither theory nor experiment, so the error could easily be remedied. That's neither tangential, nor a basis for a whole separate answer. It's just noteworthy for anyone reading the answer or for Dale if he elects to correct it.

Comment: @samerivertwice your suggested defect is incorrect. For any object $m^2 c^2 = E^2/c^2 - p^2$ which, for a massless object like a photon this reduces to $p=E/c$. Gravity is not relevant to the momentum. A photon has momentum because it is massless and it has energy. The momentum of light is well founded both in theory and in experiment. Here is a lecture that covers both the theory and some experiments: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_007S11_lec37.pdf

Comment: @Dale I disagree that it is incorrect, notwithstanding your reply.  You're assuming the background gravity of the entire universe plays no role in the kinetic energy and momentum of any given body, and in my view it remains an untested and perfectly sound hypothesis that the two are connected. Remember, I'm only advocating being impartial on the matter whereas you make an unproven claim. As a simple thought experiment: does a moving body within a totally void universe have momentum? No, clearly it does not, because it is a contradiction, since motion cannot be defined relative to nothing else.

Comment: @samerivertwice When I say “absence of gravity” I simply mean far from any gravitating body in flat spacetime, a valid physical description of some regions in this universe. Since we have no experimental access to empty universes, I have no interest in them and I think that your “clearly it does not” is far more of an “unproven claim” about which one should be impartial. As a physically relevant statement about this universe, my statement is valid and I won’t be changing it

Comment: @samerivertwice in the future, when offering suggested edits, please be direct. This is your fourth comment here, but the first where you clarified the actual issue you were raising. I had no idea you were talking about Mach’s principle in your prior responses. Mach’s principle is vague but insofar as it has been experimentally formalized (Brans Dicke gravity), it appears to not represent physics in this universe. I don’t recommend or use it, I think the constant discussion of empty universes is unscientific. If you had clarified your point earlier I could have clarified mine earlier too

Comment: @Dale I was unaware of Mach's principle and of Brans Dicke gravity so thanks for those references.  I'm not advocating for those theories either, I just think it's good scientific practice to make precise claims which don't overreach what is proven, apologies if I was insufficiently direct, it was not my intention. One of the main reasons I found it a fly in the ointment, was that the rest of the answer so methodically dealt with the matters in the question and with excellent precision.

Answer (score 3):

"Weight" can be understood as a type of force - standing on the floor, you impart a force on the floor.

Light can impart force on a surface due to the transfer of momentum involved. In other words, if a photon with momentum $p$ strikes a surface and is reflected in the opposite direction, a total momentum of $2p$ is imparted on the surface. This is called [radiation pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure). In Newtonian mechanics, you need mass to have momentum, but in relativistic mechanics, you only need energy to have momentum. And photons certainly carry energy.

So how do we compare the radiation pressure on a football field to the weight of a dime? Consider the units: Pressure is force per area, as measured in newton per square meter, N/m$^2$. You would typically think about weight as measured in kilograms, but that is actually *mass*. The weight is the force on the object due to gravity, so if the dime has mass $m$ and we have gravitational acceleration $g$, the weight is $F = m g$.

Force is also defined as *change in momentum*. So if we say $N$ photons with momentum $p$ are being reflected off a football field with area $A$ per time $t$, in total their momentum is changed by $2 N p / t$. The pressure on the football field is $2 N p/(t A)$. If we imagine a dime spread over the football field, the pressure from this dime would be $m g/A$. So, by saying that the weight of a football field of photons is the same as that of a dime, we are saying

$$\frac{2 N p}{t} = m g.$$

As for whether it is true or false, that is a simple question of estimating the parameters in this equation, which I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: +1, but one nit. "Weight" is a force, not a pressure. As you point out, you get a pressure when you distribute that force over the area of a football field.

Comment: True, corrected.

Comment: Football fields are generally not very reflective, so you should reduce that factor of 2.

Comment: *"Force is also defined as change in momentum"* - is this correct? I would say change in momentum is *impulse* (= force x time)

Comment: @PM2Ring Of course, the factor 2 is assuming a perfectly reflective football field. I use it here to make an illustrative example, clearly a more exact model can be made.

Comment: @Martin CR, force is change in momentum over time F= dp/dt, again simplified in the answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring The albedo of grass is about .25 so to be even more accurate the factor should be 1.25 rather than 1

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Dale's answer, the dimensions of a dime are $17.91$ mm diameter and $1.35$ mm thick. So the volume is $341.1$ mm$^3$.

If you spread that out over a football field with an area of $7200 \cdot 10^6$ mm$^2$, the thickness is $4.72 \cdot 10^{-8}$ mm. Or about $1/2$ an atom thick.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat - Arrgh! Thank you! Fixed!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/370098)

Comment: @BioPhysicist - It actually does, in a little broader sense. He is asking about what weight is equivalent to the force from the Sun on an object. Spreading the dime out over the field makes it clearer what weight to expect for other objects.

Comment: It's relevant information, I just don't think it fully answers the question. You even identify that it is more of an addition to an existing answer.

Comment: Why don't you write 47.2pm (picometer)?

Comment: @U.Windl - nm or Angstroms would be more common units for the atomic scale. I expected that people either could convert or would recognize that half an atom must be $0.47$ Angstrom.